# jQuery/ajax button click using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to implement a simple webpage using jQuery/Ajax.
I have 3 buttons, each of which will use ajax call to get different files from the server. The only difference is that each button has different class name, and calls different files. Everything else, such as the loading time, loading icon, success/fail message, are all the same. Therefore, I would like to write only 1 ajax function, instead of 3.

I have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "button1.txt", 
            /*more code*/
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to create another function so that this "button1" and "button1.txt" will become a variable, and whatever is returned from the function will be used in the ajax function, in which way I can reuse the ajax function 3 times.
How could you achieve this?

Comment: Can you include the three `<button>` elements `html` and corresponding `javascript` at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you everyone! I love to see how there are so many different solutions. I am amazed. I learned a lot with this simple question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need to set url on all three button like

```
<button class='button1' data-url='button1.txt'>button 1</button>
<button class='button2' data-url='button2.txt'>button 2</button>
<button class='button3' data-url='button3.txt'>button 3</button>
```

After That on your ajax.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button1, .button2, .button3").click(function(){
var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    $.ajax({
        url: url", 
        /*more code*/
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** use a data attribute say an attribute named data-url, fetch it inside your click event

Provide same class names to all the buttons.
Retrieve the value of the buttons, and pass them to the ajax call,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttonClass").click(function(){
        //var value = $(this).attr("value");
     var dataUrl = $(this).attr('data-url');
        $.ajax({
            url: dataUrl, 
            /*more code*/
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add buttons in click event

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".button1, .button2 , .button3").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "button1.txt", 
            /*more code*/
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

## 2 :

Add click onclik event in html

Comment: when `.button2` is clicked it will call `button1.txt` so that is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes to store the *file* to be access in the `$.ajax()` function. You can use a common class to attach the event handler.

*HTML*

```
<button class="button" filename="button1.txt"></button>
<button class="button" filename="button2.txt"></button>
<button class="button" filename="button3.txt"></button>
```

FileName can be fetched using [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property or jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

*Script*

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    var fileName = this.dataset.filename;
    $.ajax({
        url: fileName, 
        /*more code*/
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button1, .button2 , .button3").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        $.ajax({
            url: value, 
            /*main logic*/
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess a common class name would suffice. Although you need to have some id on your buttons to differ, yet it's not required. `this` can be used in this case.

I think this can be done with putting your ajax in a parameterised function:

```
function myAjaxCall(){
    var url = this.textContent.trim().toLowerCase()+'.txt';

    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        /*more code*/
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(myAjaxCall);
});
```

consider such buttons:

```
<button class='button'>Button1</button>
<button class='button'>Button2</button>
<button class='button'>Button3</button>
```