# Decrement value from database on button click with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am creating a carpool website and I need help with something. I have created a button and if people click on that button than  the value of free spaces in the car will decrement by one(meaning the one who will click it will reserve the place). So this value must be changed in the database and also when I refresh the page it will change on the table where I display info.This is what I have written so far but doesn't seem to make a change.Thanks in advance!

```
     <tbody>
                            <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

                             ?>
                                <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['username_krijim']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nisja']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['destinacioni']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['data_krijim']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['ora_krijim']; ?> </td>
    <td ><?php echo $row['vende_krijim']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['cmimi_krijim']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['mesazhi_krijim']; ?> </td>
    <td><form action="index_show.php" method="POST"><input class="btn btn-primary" style="background:#f2545f;" type="submit" name="rezervo" value="Rezervo"></form></td>
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['rezervo'])){
    $id_krijim=$row['id_krijimi'];
    $sql = "UPDATE krijo_itinerar SET vende_krijim=vende_krijim-1 WHERE id_krijimi='$id_krijim'";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}
?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: You need to add the action to the button, maybe using a form via POST or use AJAX to call the script

Comment: @juanbits not familiar with AJAX

Comment: An issue with understanding the difference between php and html. where to use what

Comment: if you aren't familiar with ajax, you can use a form. or search about how you can do that. you can read something at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391067/jquery-ajax-button-click-using-variable

Comment: I tried using a form with the help of @Evan but still nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Call a PHP Function on the Click of a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button)

Comment: You could explore AJAX, but it's probably better to learn the fundamental action of simply submitting a regular HTML form. There's 100's of tutorials for this.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form to send the POST request to tell the PHP to initialize.

```
<td><form action="" method="POST"><input class="btn btn-primary" style="background:#f2545f;" type="button" name="rezervo" value="Rezervo"></form></td>
<?php 
if (isset($rezervo)){
    $sql = "UPDATE krijo_itinerar SET vende_krijim=vende_krijim-1 WHERE username_krijim='".$username_krijim."'";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}
?>
```

I also don't see the variable `$username_krijim` being set. I don't know if it's somewhere else in your code but that may also be contributing to your problem.

Edit:

Ok so the problem I see are that that the variable is not being sent through PHP. That previous edit I provided won't work I'll try and think of something.

Comment: Tried it but still nothing

Comment: Where does the $username variable get sent from? @Besart

Comment: From the database. Meaning I use another file where drivers via a form decide how many free spaces they have and send it to the database via that form. At this file I am now I just connect to the database. Is there something else I should do?

Comment: Can you post more of your code (like where the $username_krijim is set?) My concern is that it's not being passed to the form therefor the query is not executing as it is incomplete.

Comment: I made a mistake I believe it should be id_krijimi='$id_krijimi' . This id is auto incremented every time a new trip is created.

Comment: Let me know if changing it works for you. If not I can take a look at the rest of the code and try to figure it out.

Comment: No it didnt work. As I said id_krijimi is created automatically by the database not the user,meaning everytime the user creates a trip and submits it that trip gets a unique id_krijimi in the database,but still I dont know why this WHERE doesnt make sense to me. Any idea what can i write after WHERE to solve it? Also where can I send the code cause it's too long for here

Comment: Your WHERE clause does look odd. Is the column called '$username_krijim' in MySQL? Because it looks like a PHP variable. Also how does the code know which ID to use? Right now it looks like you're calling a variable that does not exist.

Comment: I dont use username_krijim anymore I use id_krijimi and the column is called "id_krijimi" in the database.Exactly, theres something wrong with this whole idea.I'll try to explain better what I'm doing and see if you can help me. I have a page where the drivers can create trips.They create the trip and the data is saved in the database. Later in another page I display this data in a table so that the passegers can view the available trips and the last column of this table has buttons for every row(meaning for every trip)and if the user clicks this button ...I'll continue in the next comment

Comment: If the user clicks this button vende_krijim value of that exact trip will be decremented by one. But the thing is how to connect the button with the exact trip.  The button is displayed at the side of the trip at the table

Comment: When the trip is being displayed beside the button in the table how is it being pulled? Could you edit your original question and add the code in so I can take a look?

Comment: Thats the problem the button doesnt seem to incoorporate into the whole thing. I edited the code

Comment: Check my edit, it should help you declare the variable.

Comment: @Besart disregard that edit it won't work. Let me try some things in a test environment and get back to you.

Comment: But is username_krijim the one I should use? Cause username is the name of the driver and one driver can create more than one trip. Will this decrement the value of vende_krijim of all trips of that driver? wouldnt it be better if I use id_krijimi that is unique for every trip? If so how can I do that? Or by using username_krjim everythnings ok?

Comment: It would be better to use the ID value. I was just basing my answer off the information provided in the original question.

Comment: Ok,any idea how can I do that? No need to use mine just something cause I really need to get this to work

Comment: So I tried some small changes to the code.Now it decrements when i click the button but the problem is it still doesn't understand which one to decrement but instead decrements them all. Any idea?

Comment: @Besart that's what I realized after testing it out (I'm at work and didn't have time to fully figure it out.) You need to find a way to specify which ID to decrease. Otherwise the button will be useless. Maybe just have one button at the bottom of the page and let the user type in the ID? I can write up that code for you if you'd like.

Comment: that wont work for me. I need one button for each trip I need to find a wahyto decrement only one. Maybe its just a matter of  "{" or this isnt the right way at all but i cant seem to figure it out